# flutter how to get blob file in form of byte array from API using Dio?

Tags: flutter, image, api, dio

I need to get an image (as a byte array) from API using the Dio library as:

```
Response<List<int>> rs = await dio.get<List<int>>(url,
options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),);
```

but the response is a Truncated String like:

***identityCard: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***

what is problem and how can I get the full image?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a full image? Is this data from console print? Did you check the actual length?

Comment: yes it is not a full image, because  when I test it in postman I see the full length .

Comment: this data is from console print

Comment: Print probably cuts down data. Check the length of data.